# crypt() function not working on php 5.4.2+ Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Did I miss out any installation?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cryptography, bcrypt, password-hash

I have installed

- ubuntu stack 12.04 LTS
- PHP 5.4.2 (Latest)
- blowfish-crypt-php
- mcrypt for php
- postgres
- apache2

on my mac mini as a **mock up server**

On my **development computer**, I am using XAMPP, modified mySQL with Postgres so that I have an almost exact stack with my mock up.

This is my encryption code:

```
public function hash($string, $salt){
        $hash = crypt($string, '$2y$10$' . $salt . '$');
        return $hash;
    }
```

I will pass in the string I wish to encrypt and the salt generated by a random generator.

**OUTPUT**
On my **development computer**, I was able to hash my password successfully with crypt() function and salt using this function.

$salt -> HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya 
$hash -> $2y$10$$$$$.T8Ru0j8p7ULN2QIAegbSiVTqmIIIc/a

However on my **mock up server**, the output was totally different! it basically just lump the salt into the middle of the *to be encrypted string*!

$salt -> HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya 
$hash -> $2y$10$HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya$

I am new to encryption and hope that a kind soul will help! Thanks!

Comment: For PHP 5.4 you should be using [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), which will also allow your script to continue to work when you upgrade to php 5.5+, but without that library. See [the docs](http://php.net/password_hash) for usage.

Comment: And also, on your development server, the hash you have listed above is incorrect if you used the salt "HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya". This salt should be contained in the hash.

Comment: @Mike I don't quite get the meaning that the salt should be contained in the hash. The salt will be passed in as a parameter and concatenated before hashing **$hash = crypt($string, "$2y$10$HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya$")**

Comment: @Mike should it be something like this? **$2y$10$HGhfwjgr0lGa31Ya$$$$$.T8Ru0j8p7ULN2QIAegbSiVTqmIIIc/a**

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. One thing, see all those $$$$$ in the middle? That means your salt is sub-optimal length (and who knows about the "randomness" that was used to create it). Like I said in my first comment, don't try to roll your own password hashing. Use the built-in libraries.

Comment: @Mike, thanks! integrating password_compat actually solves the whole issue and from what I read it also solves the security loopholes found in php v5.3.6 for bcrypt().